# Dynamic path in document function()

Tags: xslt

The XML file name is specific but I need to build a dynamic path.  I have tried using a variable to build the path but it didn't work:

```
<xsl:variable name="path">
   ...conditional code
</xsl:variable>     <xsl:value-of select="document('myXML.xml')/worksheets/$path"/>
```

2.0 solutions ok.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an explanation and a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluation of any dynamically-generated XPath expression is not supported by the XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 standards. It will be supported in **[XSLT 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-xslt-21-20100511/#element-evaluate)**.

**If the dynamically-generated XPath expression is not too complex, the technique in this answer can be used successfully**:

[Retrieving XML node from a path specified in an attribute value of another node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015942/retrieving-xml-node-from-a-path-specified-in-an-attribute-value-of-another-node/3017752#3017752)

Comment: Dimitre's solution is very cool for simple expressions. I also added an example to that topic using EXLT's dynamic:evaluate function, which should be essentially the same as the saxon:evaluate solution that Max mentions in his answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015942/retrieving-xml-node-from-a-path-specified-in-an-attribute-value-of-another-node/3017752#answer-3017543

Answer (score 1):

You need an extension function, XPath 2.0 does not support dynamic compilation/evaluation. Saxon has `saxon:evaluate`. Even if your processor does not support such function you might be able to implement it yourself as an extension function.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to get the saxon:evaluate() function to work with a document() function.  I get a static error xPath xPression.
<xsl:value-of select="document('myxml.xml')/saxon:evaluate($formPath)"/>

Comment: @johkar: Your XPath expression is wrong, you should do something like this: `saxon:evaluate(concat('document(\'myxml.xml\')/', $formPath))`

Comment: @johkar: Also, the saxon:evaluate function is avaliable on Professional and Enterprise editions.